# How to show accusative month name form in view title for russian locale?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with `lang: 'ru'` option and in a view title I can see a month name in russian like '14 - 20 сентябр**ь** 2015'.

But according to russian grammar it should be '14 - 20 сентябр**я** 2015' - accusative month name form.

I see fullcalendar lang-all.js file has accusative month name forms for russian locale. Is there any way to show them in view title(for me it's related to week and day views)?

---

Update:
The original issue was fixed: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2870

Comment: If you're hosting the files, you could edit `lang-all.js` and/or `lang/ru.js`

Comment: That's true, but unfortunately it will change translation in all places and it's going to be a bit incorrect. For example for the month view I need month name in nominative form - like it is now. For week and day views I need month name in accusative form - but now it's taken from one place and it's nominative forms. Currently I did simple title string replacing in `renderView` handler for specific views. A bit ugly but it's working:)